# Is there an equivalent of Entrez queries for local BLAST?

Tags: blast, bash, blastn, entrez

I have been having some trouble with running command line BLASTn remotely. Therefore, upon recommendations, and considering I have >100 searches planned, I am considering just downloading the nt database (thankfully possible).

My issue is that one of the settings that proved valuable with my data in WebBlast is running an Entrez query. I get more useful results for each query when instead of one search, I run three, with each of the sub-searches delimited by subject sequence length (e.g. `-entrez_query 700:1000[slen]` to only get the results which are between 700 and 1000 nucleotides long).

WebBlast and remote Blast have that, local Blast does not.

Since I only really need 2 Entrez queries, I guess it would not be conceptually impossible to get my copy of nt database as FASTA, and then run a script to split it into three directories (700-1000nt, 1000-1400nt, the rest while discarding all<700 nt), then make three blastable databases out of it. However it does feel rather inelegant. I was wondering if anyone might have a better solution!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139871/discussion-on-question-by-laura-is-there-an-equivalent-of-entrez-queries-for-loc).

Answer (score 1):

I looked back at the question and have a more comprehensive solution.

1. There is no option for `-entrez_query` on a local blast search. The information is [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279684/table/appendices.T.options_common_to_all_blast/)

> entrez_query   Restrict search with the given Entrez query. Remote searches only.

There is an option without `-outfmt` for `length` and that is worth investigating.

> length means Alignment length

2. #### Perl one liner solution to NCBI's many parameter problem

a) Preprocess your fasta file into separate databases of the required length ... by turning a fasta flatfile db into one where all the subject sequences are 700 - 1000.

```
perl -0777 -nle 'while (/^(>.+\n^[AGCT-NRYMKWS]{700,1000})\n/gm){print $1,"\n"}' example.fa > example700-1000.fa
```

b) Now make the database on the restricted length fasta flatfile db,

```
makeblastdb -in example700-1000.fa -parse_seqids -blastdb_version 5  -out laura700-1000.db -title "Laura 700 - 1000" -dbtype nucl
```

This db will now contain an equivalent of the `-entrez_query 700:1000[slen]`. Obviously, you would need to make a new db for each change in the sequence length query. Note the option `-taxid_map`.

c) Finally, run the blast search on the restricted length blast db.

```
blastn -query laura.fas -db laura700-1000.db -evalue 1e-6 -num_threads 4 -out blasthits.txt
```

---

##### Code testing

**Input is test.fa**

```
>here
AGAGACGTAGAGAAAAAAAAAA
>here2
TAGAGA
>here3
AGAGACGTAGAGA
```

Modified perl oneliner because sequence length is different,

```
perl -0777 -nle 'while (/^(>.+\n^[AGC-T]{6,13})\n/gm){print $1,"\n"}' test.fa
```

**Output**

```
>here2
TAGAGA
>here3
AGAGACGTAGAGA
```

Thus the sequence that was outside the range 6 to 13 (sequence `here2` and `here3`) is excluded (`here`). This seems alot easier to me that all those `blastn` options.

**Note** NRYMKWS refer to the degenerate nucleotide code

Answer (score 0):

"Often, one needs to search ... a specific subset of sequences within an existing database. For these type of searches a convenient way to conduct them is by creating a virtual BLAST database"

From "Use blastdb_aliastool to manage the BLAST databases" https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK569848/